# JSONDecodeError in Django project

Tags: javascript, json, django

I'm a beginner. I do everything as in the django ecommerce website course from the link, but it does not work for me. I also tried other stack overflow solutions but they didn't help. I have this error when i go to /update_item/ and the data is not showing up in the terminal:

Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

[image: error png]

[tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woORrr3QNh8&list=PL-51WBLyFTg0omnamUjL1TCVov7yDTRng&index=3&ab_channel=DennisIvyDennisIvyZweryfikowano)

cart.js

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var productId = this.dataset.product
    var action = this.dataset.action
    console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)
    console.log('USER:', user)
})
}
function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

    var url = '/update_item/'

    fetch(url, {
        method:'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
    })
    .then((response) => {
       return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
        location.reload()
    });
}
```

views.py

```
def updateItem(request):
data = json.loads(request.body)
productId = data['productId']
action = data['action']
print('Action:', action)
print('Product:', productId)

return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

store.html

```
<div class="row">
{% for product in products %}
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="{{ product.imageURL }}">
        <div class="box-element product">
            <h6><strong>{{product.name}}</strong></h6>
            <hr>

            <button data-product="{{product.id}}" data-action="add"  class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
            <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="#">View</a>
            <h4 style="display: inline-block; float: right"><strong>{{product.price|floatformat:2}}PLN</strong></h4>

        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: What exactly calls the function `updateUserOrder`? I don't see anything calling it?

Comment: you're right i forgot to call a function in a loop, now it works, thank you

Answer (score 0):

the `request.body` in line2 of `views.py` contains byte rather than string. So you need to decode it to string in order to get the data.
so your code in `views.py` must look like-:

```
def updateItem(request):
    data = request.POST
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)

return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)
```

Comment: still not working and showing the same error

Comment: MultiValueDictKeyError now

Comment: print data and see the if you are getting the values from the frontend

Comment: i didn't call a function in a for loop...  my mistake, but thanks for help